# Is there a way around repetitive tables in Subqueries?

Tags: php, mysql

Notice that I'm calling and joining the same tables for my main query and subquery.

Now my actually query is using many more subqueries like that.

Is there a way to call a subquery field from the main query thus eliminating the need to reuse the same join tables in the subqueries? I want to make it more efficient without sacrificing speed.

```
SELECT tb1.id, tb1.title,

(SELECT tb1.title 
FROM table1 AS tb1
JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS tb3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id 
WHERE tb1.id > '123' LIMIT 1) AS next

FROM table1 AS tb1
JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS tb3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id
WHERE tb1.id='123'
```

Comment: Subqueries with `LIMIT 1` are usually fast enough with proper indexing.

Comment: I almost submitted an incorrect answer... I think.  Can you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: The query is just for show but I'm wondering if instead of calling and joining tb1, tb2, tb3 in each subquery.. if I could use the joins straight from the main query. So a lot like the answer bellow just without creating a table view maybe by aliasing the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) to abstract that query.

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_view AS 
SELECT 
tb1.id as id,
tb1.title as title  
FROM table1 AS tb1
JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS tb3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id
```

The shorter query would be

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  title,
  (SELECT title FROM tbl_view
  WHERE id > '123' LIMIT 1) AS next
FROM 
  tbl_view
WHERE id='123'
```

Comment: That's very interesting but the query now takes twice as long to run. I wonder if there's another way without sacrificing speed.

Comment: Additionally, you can try creating indexes on tb1.id and tb1.title.